# Add ToolTip to "Word" in a context menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I want to add a tooltip to a menu item.  On the menu there is the word "DELETE" and when the mouse hovers over the word I want a tooltip displayed.  I though of using 'ToolTipService.SetToolTip();'.

This is where the items contained in the menu are set...

```
protected virtual void SetContextMenuItems()
    {
        // -- Add condition for ReadOnly + ReadOnly Attribute to AreaEntity
        if (this.ViewMode == Common.Core.ViewModes.RealTime)
        {
            AreaEntity ae = viewModel.EntityViewContext as AreaEntity;
            if (((UserContext.Instance.IsAdmin() && (ae.Scope.Value == "global" || ae.Scope.Value == string.Empty)) ||
                    ae.OwnerPosition.Value == CoreServices.Instance.CurrentPosition.Configuration.Name)
                    && !((this.MapInstance.Parent as Grid).Parent is PIPMap))
            {
                menuItem = new ContextMenuItem();
                //menuItem.DisplayText = "Delete"; // -- Could be dynamic based off type "Edit Polygon (Circle, etc.)"
                menuItem.DisplayText = CoreServices.Instance.GetString("Delete");
                cmd = new MR.CommandBridge.Common.Command.DelegateCommand(DeleteShape, CanDelete);
                menuItem.Command = cmd;
                this.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

Methods 'DeleteShape' and 'CanDelete':

```
public void DeleteShape(object param)
    {
        EntityStore.Instance.DeleteEntity(this.ViewModel.EntityViewContext);
    }

    public bool CanDelete(object param)
    {
        GetRulesForShape();
        bool isInFilter = false;
        EntityCollection<Entity> lists = EntitySync.Instance.Cache["entityCollection"];
        foreach (Entity list in lists)
        {
            isInFilter = (list as ListEntity).FilterList.Filters.Count(a => (a.FilterType == FilterTypes.WithinZone && a.Value == this.viewModel.EntityViewContext.Uri) ||
                                                                            (a.FilterType == FilterTypes.MultipleFilter && a.Filters.Count(b => b.FilterType == FilterTypes.WithinZone && b.Value == this.viewModel.EntityViewContext.Uri) > 0)) > 0;
            if (isInFilter) break;
        }
        return !HasRules && !CoreServices.Instance.ZoneFilters.Contains(this.viewModel.Area.Uri) && gfEditor.dm != GeofenceEditor.DrawMode.DrawEdit && !isInFilter;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I made some adjustments to your class.
Somehow I got the feeling your mixing up things like control and bindings.
We'll see. ;)

I've also made some comments, maybe you can shed some light over then.

```
public class ContextMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    public ContextMenuItem()
        :base()
    {
    }

    //Replace by Header
    //
    //public string DisplayText { get; set; }


    //Can this be replaced by build in CommandParameter
    //
    private Dictionary<string, object> _parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    private Func<ContextMenuItem, List<ContextMenuItem>> _getMenuItems = null; 

    //Already available
    //public DelegateCommand Command { get; set; }


    //What does this function do?
    public Func<ContextMenuItem, List<ContextMenuItem>> GetMenuItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _getMenuItems;
        }
        set
        {
            _getMenuItems = value;
        }
    }


    public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters
    {
        get
        {
            return _parameters;
        }
    }

    //Can be replaced by base Items
    //
    //private List<ContextMenuItem> _menuItems = new List<ContextMenuItem>();
    //public List<ContextMenuItem> ChildMenuItems
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        return _menuItems;
    //    }
    //}

    private bool _isChecked = false;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set { _isChecked = value; }
    }

    // -- Command or implementer could provide a handler for all commands - might be simpler for now
    // -- I think there could be a better way to route commands but I'll thin on it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this simply be done in .css?

```
.yourclass:hover{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

or target it with jquery?

Comment: I am using c# not .css.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
menuitem.ToolTip = "Delete";
```

Normally a contextmenu can exist of regular MenuItems. I used it often.
;)

Comment: When I try this 'ToolTip' doesn't exist.  It wants me to create a property or field stub for it... not sure why.

Comment: this contextmenuitem, is it a custom control?

Comment: If contextmenuitem is a custom control, can you please provide the code of it? Maybe I can try it locally

Answer (score 0):

Context menu items have the ToolTipText property:

```
menuItem.ToolTipText = "ToolTip Text Here";
```

Comment: When I try this 'ToolTip' doesn't exist.  It wants me to create a property or field stub for it... not sure why.

Comment: I did try 'ToolTipText' as well.